# How do I exclude main pages and link only to sub pages?

Tags: links

I have read the following but I'm still confused

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

At my website

http://alluvialtrading.com/

I would like for example "Who We Are", "What We Do" to link to nothing and only have sub pages.  Is this possible?

Comment: I went back and accepted the best answers

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) . This way you'll be able to construct your own menus and link them to whatever you link or not to link at all. 
I've also used "Redirectify" plugin once, but I think it was removed. There is ["Redirect"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirect/) though which is probably the same , but I haven't used it